# Minimal subfield and equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

I was wondering, how does one show:

$\mathbb{Q}(a\sqrt{b},a\sqrt{b}b)=\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ for $a=\sqrt[4]{2}$, $b=i$?

One thing I noticed is that  we must have $i=b, a\in \mathbb{Q}(a\sqrt{b},a\sqrt{b}b)$ This means,

$\mathbb{Q}(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(a\sqrt{b},a\sqrt{b}b)$. However, i'm not sure how to prove the other direction. In fact I suspect the other direction does not hold

Comment: What is the square root of $i$?

Comment: @Wuestenfux $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question correct, but from my reading $\sqrt 2=a^2\in \mathbb Q(a,b)$, so $\sqrt b=\frac {\sqrt 2}2+\frac{\sqrt 2}2i\in \mathbb Q(a,b)$.

Comment: @fantasie right. Is $a\in$  $\mathbb{Q}(a\sqrt{b},a\sqrt{b}b)$?

Comment: Yes, because divide the second one by the first one gives $b=i$, and square the first one gives $-\frac{\sqrt 2}2$. Now you can write $\sqrt b$ just as comments above, and then retrieve $a$.